# How to check if a buy condition met in the last X days in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I have screener function in TradingView. In this script, I want to check if my BUY condition met in the last X days. I tried the code below but it didn't work. How can I achive it?

```
screener() =>
    //Calculations

    // Determine sell and buy signals
    buyCondition = c[2] == color.red and c[1] == color.red and c == color.green
    buyCondition = buyCondition and timenow - 10 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 <= time

    [buyCondition ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare the time of the last condition to the time of the current bar:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Condition in last 10D", "", true)
buyCondition = ta.rising(close, 5)
buyInLastTenDays = time - time[nz(ta.barssince(buyCondition))] < 10 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

plotchar(buyCondition, "buyCondition", "•", location.top)
plotchar(buyInLastTenDays, "buyInLastTenDays", "—", location.bottom)
plot(ta.barssince(buyCondition), "ta.barssince(buyCondition)", display = display.data_window)
```

Comment: i tried it in a screener function for 3 days but it showed me the buy signal at the 9th bar from last.
What is wrong with it?


```
screener =>
    buySignal = ta.crossover(MAvg, OTT[2])
    sellSignal = ta.crossunder(MAvg, OTT[2])
    
    buyInLast3days= time - time[ta.barssince(buySignal)] < 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

    [buyInLast3days}
```

Comment: Hard to say without complete code, but you can try plotting a label when your `buySignal` variable is true, to see if it behaves the way you expect.